# WEB Firbase Remote Config - fetchAndActivate method fetching all the values from remote config, I want only single value to be fetched

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Here is my code snippet which I am using, everything is working as expected but only issue is that fetchAndActivate method fetches all value from remote and caches them.
Is there any way of feching and activating only single value from remote config?

```
fetchAndActivate(remoteConfig).then(
      _res => {
        const val = getValue(remoteConfig, "MPEmptyCartRecos");
        const value = JSON.parse(val.asString());
        this.setState({widgetConfigResponse: value});
    },
    err => {
        console.log("error >>>>>", err);
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to fetch just a single value from Remote Config, but of course your code can decide to use only one of the fetched values.

Comment: will there be any performance issues due to this?

Comment: As we are expecting our response size to increase upto 1000 key/value pairs or remote config parameters

Comment: You seem to be trying to micro-manage Remote Config, which is not recommended. Instead, fetch-and-activate the remote config once when your app starts, and then look up the specific config value you need in other places in the code.